# Node.js server gets stuck after few requests when using passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm writing a node.js app using passport for authentication. I noticed a strange behavior: 
If I use this code, my server gets stuck after 10 requests (I trimmed out some non relevant code):

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var MySqlBl = require('./server/db/mysqlbl');

var app = express();    

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.userName);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (username, done) {
    var mysqlbl = new MySqlBl();
    mysqlbl.getUser(username, onGetUserCompleted);

    function onGetUserCompleted(user) {
        if (user === undefined) {
            done('Problem deserializing user');
        }

        done(null, user);
    };
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    var mysqlbl = new MySqlBl();
    mysqlbl.getUser(username, onGetUserCompleted);

    function onGetUserCompleted(user) {
            return done(null, user);
        };
    }
));

app.use(app.router);

require('./server/routes')(app);
```

I tried to totally remove any passport related code, and my server worked just fine, but I still want to use the passport lib...
Any help please? I tried everything, I need some direction.

Comment: I'm not aware of the MySqlBl module, but it would seem it could be leaking database connections if you never close up after done with it.

Comment: As @JoachimIsaksson said, your MySqlBl module is probably opening connections and never closing them, which fills the [`globalAgent` socket pool](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent). When the pool is full, further requests are on hold, waiting for a socket to become free.

Comment: move the db connection to a module, so you can reuse the db object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the help, found the problem!

The main cause to the servers' lack of response is that the `deserializeUser` function never called `done`.

That was because I had a problem with leaking connections to the DB.